# WPF why does listviewitem not appear in list of VisualTreeHelper.HitTest results?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have below an example where you can hit test a click on a window. However, Even when I click on the listviewitem, it does not list the listviewitem in HitTestResults. Instead, it lists the actual textblock in the listviewitem and the other controls higher up the tree. Is ListViewItem not a visual? why doesn't it get returned when enumerating all results.

Instead, I get these hittestresults:

Textblock, Border, Border, ScrollViewer, Border

shouldn't it be Textblock, ListViewItem, Border, Border, ScrollViewer?

Full Code:

```
<Window 
  x:Class="TestApp.Window1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:Test="clr-namespace:TestApp"
  Title="Window1" Height="900" Width="900"
  Loaded="Window_Loaded"
  xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
  >
  <ListView
    x:Name="TestListView"
    >
    <ListViewItem x:Name="ListViewItem1">
      <Label Content="HEy how are you" />
    </ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem />

  </ListView>


</Window>



  public partial class Window1 : Window
  {
    public Window1()
    {
      BindingDataSet ds = new BindingDataSet();
      this.DataContext = ds;

      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      this.PreviewMouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Window1_PreviewMouseDown);
      bool b = ListViewItem1.IsHitTestVisible;


      //ItemsControl.Items.Add(new object());
    }

    void Window1_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

      hitResultsList.Clear();
      Point pt = e.GetPosition(TestListView);
      VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(TestListView, null,
       new HitTestResultCallback(MyHitTestResult),
       new PointHitTestParameters(pt));


    }
    // Return the result of the hit test to the callback. 
    List<DependencyObject> hitResultsList = new List<DependencyObject>();

    public HitTestResultBehavior MyHitTestResult(HitTestResult result)
    {
      // Add the hit test result to the list that will be processed after the enumeration.
      hitResultsList.Add(result.VisualHit);

      // Set the behavior to return visuals at all z-order levels. 
      return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please justify why this question should not be closed as a duplicate of your [Why do listviewitems not appear in hit test results?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054370/why-do-listviewitems-not-appear-in-hit-test-results) question.

Comment: i gave him credit for the answer because that's what i ended up doing, but i still have no clue why listbox items don't appear in hit tests to begin with. I would like to understand the architecture, so I made a small test case that anyone could duplicate in the hope that someone could explain why the items themselves aren't in hit test results. Reading the Hit Testing in the Visual Layer article on msdn hasn't helped me figure it out yet, so even though my code is now working, I would like to better know how the hit testing system works.

Comment: +1 Perfectly justified.